# Is $P(g) = \arg\min\limits_{f \in \mathcal{F}}||g-f||_{2,\mu}^2$ a contraction or non-expensive projection?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis, analysis

Is 
$$P(g) = \arg\min_{f \in \mathcal{F}}||g-f||_{2,\mu}^2 = \int \left(f(x)-g(x)\right)^2 \mu(dx)$$ a contraction or non-expensive projection? i.e., $$||P(g)-P(f)||_{2,\mu}^2 \leq ||g-f||_{2,\mu}^2$$

$\mathcal{F}$ is a function space, but I don't know any properties of it. Do I need any assumption of it if I want to prove the above projection is a contraction or non-expensive projection? Thanks!

Comment: What's the definition of the norm $\| \cdot\|_{2,\mu}$?

Comment: $||f||_{2,\mu}^2 = \int f(x)^2 \mu(dx)$

Comment: What do you mean by $\|P(g)-P(f)\|_{2,\mu}^2$? Aren't $P(f)$ and $P(g)$ just two real numbers?

Comment: No, they are 2 functions. $P(f)$ is the projection of $f$ in function space $\mathcal{F}$

Comment: Then you'd need to write $\text{argmin}$ instead of $\inf$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks. I corrected it.

Comment: Are you sure you got the question correct though? It still doesn't make sense to project onto the whole space $\mathcal F$ since $P$ would be just the identity map.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90177/discussion-between-coolcat-and-bigbearzzz).

Comment: It makes sense to take the argmin on suitable subsets of the underlying space that $g$ is drawn from (e.g. closed vector subspaces).